# Selecting from the menu after clicking selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select the latest available date after clicking on the menu from the following website:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from _datetime import datetime
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = "http://ausweisung.ivw-online.de/index.php?i=1161&a=o52802"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
driver.get("http://ausweisung.ivw-online.de/" + Link)
time.sleep(random.randint(7, 10))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="iform_ausweisung_szm"]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/select').click()
```

However, even at the first step I get the following error:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <select name="a" class="inaktiv" onchange="document.getElementById('iform_ausweisung_szm').submit();">...</select> is not clickable at point (875, 31). Other element would receive the click: <div class="bread">...</div>
```

How to get rid of the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 2 options to handle this issue.

Option 1: scroll to the select and then click

```
 listEle = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="iform_ausweisung_szm"]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/select')
 listEle.location_once_scrolled_into_view # this will scroll to the element
 #click on the element
 listEle.click()
```

Option 2: using javascript

```
 listEle = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="iform_ausweisung_szm"]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/select')
 #click using javascript
 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",listEle)
```

Comment: No, for some reason, it does not load the new page after clicking

Comment: Are you still getting `ElementClickInterceptedException` when clicked using one of the above options?

Comment: Basically, it skips that line, where it suppose to click

Comment: If add click to the first line I get
ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <select name="a" class="inaktiv" onchange="document.getElementById('iform_ausweisung_szm').submit();">...</select> is not clickable at point (875, 31). Other element would receive the click: <div class="bread">...</div>

Comment: Are you using option 1 or 2. Can you print(listEle) before clicking and make sure you are pointing to the right element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194840/discussion-between-supputuri-and-edyvedy13).

Answer (score 1):

Try having the element scroll into view:

```
xml_item = self.driver.find_element_by_name('//*[@id="iform_ausweisung_szm"]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/select')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);", xml_item)
xml_item.click() # Or any other action item.
```

In most cases, the issue is that the element is on the page somewhere, but it is not in the active window for selenium to take any action against it.